# Deep Query with TFS 2010 Api

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

Can any one tell me how i can make deep queries with the TFS API and to avoid to query the TFS database(miscrofot said that is not a best thing).

I'll explain my idea below:
I have a tree like that

```
  $/tfs/ProjectNameXX/Version/1/SR/SR0 (subdirectory)
                                   SR1 (subdirectory)
```

How i can make a simple query with the API for retrieve for example:

- the version of the ProjectNameXX
- SRs of the ProjectNameXX where the version equals to 1 and "project
  name" = ProjectNameXX

I have made some methods to retrieve data like the example above but it's not a good thing because if the structure of the tree is changed :nothing is going to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming you're talking about source control and not areas.

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection("http://url");
VersionControlServer _versionControlServer = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
versionControlServer.GetItems("$//tfs/*.*", VersionSpec.Latest, RecursionType.Full, DeletedState.NonDeleted, ItemType.File).Items;
```

That will get your a list of all files recursively, you'll then have to iterate through them manually to figure out what you want.

But yes you'll still have issues if the structure changes.

Comment: Yes it is about the source contol.But your solution is the same i do in this moment.I can make queries directly from the database from differents tables but it's a good idea for us(for microsoft is not)?

Comment: DbQueries are not recommended because the schema may change, and it is usually quite complex to get what you want.  I'm not sure what the issue is with using the API? can you explain further